# Hindi fonts missing from QGIS UI

Tags: qgis

My QGIS is not showing Hindi Fonts. It happened after I formatted my Windows 10. To fix it, I installed Hindi Fonts, Google Input tools, etc. but didn't work. The Hindi fonts work in other software but not in QGIS as shown in the image below. 
QGIS version 2.18.3 to 2.18.14
[image]
Is there any fix for this?

Comment: I just cross checked to see if its possible to make changes in the QGIS settings and noticed that there might be issues with hindi text. The text appears as black squares just as it appears in your image.

Comment: Yes same for me. It is everywhere Hindi text is shown even in plugins. So I am not the only one with this problem...

Comment: @mapperx which operating system are you using?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am using fonts from https://hindifonts.org/ and they are not unicodes. text file method did not work. it only shows as english letters and not in a correct way either.

Comment: Do you see black boxes like the above images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is fixed by putting text file containing a Hindi font in desktop. According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/434861) and the link shared there, creating the file in desktop makes Windows Explorer to render Unicode fonts.

Now the Hindi fonts are showing properly.